# JAAS microservice authentication

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, ejb, jaas

I am trying to design a JAAS microservice which handles user authentication for multiple J2EE applications. Currently we have multiple applications which authenticate against our LDAP and have seperate role-systems.
Now I am stuck at designing the interface between the application and the authentication backend.

**Via custom LoginModule:** Design a custom login module which uses a nonsecured EJB interface from our LoginService to authenticate and authorize, but i remembered reading that login modules can't be injected with EJBs / use EJBs.

Is this the right starting point, or do i have other possibilities to refactor JAAS security out of our applications? Has somebody done something like that before?

Answer (score 1):

I had been curious about Java security some time before. I have found nice framework [Picketlink](http://picketlink.org/).

Despite it needs quite high threshold to entry, it is much more flexible than JAAS and handles most typical needs.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! But sadly i have the requirement to use JAAS.